# Redis standalone stop working (timeouts) on master replica sync

Tags: kubernetes, redis, bitnami

We use a redis cache in out kubernetes cluster which stops working really randomly. It's a Standalone version based on this image: bitnami/redis:6.0.15

As custom parameters we use:

MASTER true

REDIS_AOF_ENABLED no

Every time when the redis stop working I see the following logs:

```
Jul 5 13:30:27 redis-0 redis 1:M 05 Jul 2022 11:30:27.060 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
Jul 5 13:30:27 redis-0 redis 1:M 05 Jul 2022 11:30:27.090 * Background saving started by pid 364
Jul 5 13:31:34 redis-0 redis 364:C 05 Jul 2022 11:31:34.307 * DB saved on disk
Jul 5 13:31:34 redis-0 redis 364:C 05 Jul 2022 11:31:34.341 * RDB: 431 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
Jul 5 13:31:34 redis-0 redis 1:M 05 Jul 2022 11:31:34.488 * Background saving terminated with success
Jul 5 13:32:35 redis-0 redis 1:M 05 Jul 2022 11:32:35.022 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
Jul 5 13:32:35 redis-0 redis 1:M 05 Jul 2022 11:32:35.052 * Background saving started by pid 365
-----
Jul 5 13:32:40 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:40.436 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
Jul 5 13:32:40 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:40.436 * REPLICAOF 178.20.40.200:8886 enabled (user request from 'id=71457 addr=10.0.16.46:14072 fd=12 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=47 qbuf-free=32721 argv-mem=24 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=61488 events=r cmd=slaveof user=default')
Jul 5 13:32:41 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:41.316 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
Jul 5 13:32:41 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:41.316 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Jul 5 13:32:41 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:41.362 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
Jul 5 13:32:41 redis-0 redis Error 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:41.409 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
Jul 5 13:32:42 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:42.316 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
Jul 5 13:32:42 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:42.317 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Jul 5 13:32:42 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:42.366 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
Jul 5 13:32:42 redis-0 redis Error 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:42.415 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
Jul 5 13:32:43 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:43.317 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
Jul 5 13:32:43 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:43.317 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Jul 5 13:32:43 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:43.366 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
Jul 5 13:32:43 redis-0 redis Error 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:43.416 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
Jul 5 13:32:44 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:44.320 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
Jul 5 13:32:44 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:44.320 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Jul 5 13:32:44 redis-0 redis 1:S 05 Jul 2022 11:32:44.370 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
```

Then I see that the queue increase, but I need to kill the pod to restart redis otherwise it will not work anymore.

````
next: GET 6126674261995698486, 
inst: 1, 
qu: 0,  // queue => waiting operations
qs: 17, 
aw: False, 
rs: ReadAsync, 
ws: Idle, 
in: 0, // bytes waiting from input stream
in-pipe: 0, 
out-pipe: 0, 
serverEndpoint: redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379, 
mc: 1/1/0, 
mgr: 10 of 10 available, // tread pool
clientName: production-9bbd94544-nlmv7, 
IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=5,Max=1000),  // no busy threads
WORKER: (Busy=14,Free=32753,Min=256,Max=32767), 
v: 2.2.4.27433```

```Timeout performing GET (3000ms), 
next: 2865582319381864083, 
inst: 0, 
qu: 0, 
qs: 333, 
aw: False, 
rs: ReadAsync, 
ws: Idle, 
in: 0, 
in-pipe: 0, 
out-pipe: 0, 
serverEndpoint: redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379, 
mc: 1/1/0, 
mgr: 10 of 10 available, 
clientName: production-58c7874fd8-tdcpz, 
IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), 
WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=256,Max=32767), 
v: 2.2.4.27433
````

````
next: GET 6126674261995698486, 
inst: 47, 
qu: 0, 
qs: 21368, 
aw: False, 
rs: ReadAsync,
 ws: Idle, 
 in: 0, 
 in-pipe: 0, 
 out-pipe: 0, 
 serverEndpoint: redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379, 
 mc: 1/1/0, 
 mgr: 10 of 10 available, 
 clientName: production-9bbd94544-nlmv7, 
 IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=5,Max=1000), 
 WORKER: (Busy=162,Free=32605,Min=256,Max=32767), 
v: 2.2.4.27433```


Has anyone an idea? 
Thank you.
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the redis service is running? `kubectl get service/redis`. It seems like the service is unable to receive traffic, which is possible if there are no pods to receive it.

Comment: When this happened, I can still connect to the pod. But then the redis-cli does not react anymore